# Filling Array of type long and short with random values

Tags: arrays

I'm having trouble filling an array of type long and type short with random numbers using a random-number generator. I was able to do this with arrays of types double and float, but no luck with the other two. The code I have come up with only prints out 1's for all 10 elements in the arrays.

```
const int size = 10;
short int* myShorts = new short[size];
long int* myLongs = new long[size];
...
...
// short fill
std::cout << "Short Array: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *(myShorts + i) = rand() / short(RAND_MAX)*50.f + 1.f;
    std::cout << i << ": " << std::setprecision(4) << *(myShorts + i) << std::endl;
}

// long fill
std::cout << "Long Array: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *(myLongs + i) = rand() / long(RAND_MAX)*50.f + 1.f;
    std::cout << i << ": " << std::setprecision(4) << *(myLongs + i) << std::endl;
}
```

And my result is this:

```
Short Array:
0: 1
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1
6: 1
7: 1
8: 1
9: 1

Long Array:
0: 1
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1
6: 1
7: 1
8: 1
9: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
*(myLongs + 1) = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX * 50.f + 1.f;
```

?

Comment: Whenever that happens i get answers without numbers to the right of the decimal point. Just ints basically.

Comment: The floats are cast to *long int* because this is the type of *myLongs*... If you declare *myLongs* as float - it works...

Comment: Oh wait my bad, your code worked great. I was expecting the wrong solution. Thanks! @obe